# Django -- dissallowing field editing?

Tags: django

I'm not sure how to word this, so I'll describe the scenario:

I'm setting up a method for budgeting. Each budget item has up to 3 categories (a 'main', a 'sub' and a 'sub sub'). So, I have this:

```
model: Main_Category
model: Sub_Category
model: Sub_Sub_Category

model: Budget_Item
    field: Description
    main_cat: FK --> Main_Category
    sub_cat: FK --> Sub_Category
    sub_sub_cat: FK --> Sub_Sub_Category
    amount: decimal
    item_used?: boolean
```

Now, the user can create as main categories as they like -- they can create a huge list of "main" categories, "sub" categories, and as many "sub sub" categories as they need. After creating a category, they can go back and edit it (maybe they misspelled it orriginally) or even delete the category all together.

Then, they can create as many `Budget_Items` as they like, organizing them by the categories. When a `Budget_Item` is "used" (a purchase is made) the `isUsed` field is set to `True`.

What I want is to **disallow** editing or deleting of categories if that category has been "used" through a purchase.

For example:

I create a `main` category called "Fule". I realise I misspelled it so I edit the category and call it "Fuel". Then I create a `Budget_Item` whose main category is "Fuel" for $50. Then I go out and spend $50 on gas, and mark my `Budget_Item` as "used". Now that I've used the `Budget_Item`, I **do not** want to be able to edit the category "Fuel". That record needs to be locked down somehow.

Does this make sense? Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent the categories from being deleted you need to pass the on_delete=models.PROTECT parameter to the foreign key, like this:

```
class BudgetItem(models.Model):
    ....
    main_cat = models.ForeignKey(MainCategory, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='budgets1')
    sub_cat = models.ForeignKey(SubCategory, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='budgets2')
    sub_sub_cat = models.ForeignKey(SubSubCategory, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='budgets3')
    ....
```

You can read more on the delete part in the Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete).

To prevent the models from being edited you can override the save method of each category model to detect if the category model has a budget item that has being used through purchase:

```
# Overriding the save method of the MainCategory model
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # Checking if there aren't budget items that belongs to this category and
    # has been used through a purchase so this category can be changed.
    if not self.budgets1.filter(item_used=True).exists():
        super(MainCategory, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Note that the part self.budgets1 its possible because the related_name parameter was passed to the category field creation.

This code is only an example of what you could do, but there are many ways to implement what you want, the trick it's to detect if the category can't be modified and stop from being saved in some way.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the Django Admin, you can override the [`has_change_permission`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.has_change_permission) and [`has_delete_permission`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.has_delete_permission) methods for your `Category` model admin.

In the methods, you have access to the category object, so it shouldn't be too difficult to check whether there are related `Budget_Item`s with `isUsed` set to `True`.